# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet ReportServlet1 threw exception

Tags: servlets, pentaho

```
type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet ReportServlet1 threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet ReportServlet1 threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pentaho/reporting/engine/classic/core/ClassicEngineBoot
    org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.samples.ReportServlet.init(ReportServlet.java:48)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

1. iam trying to display the pentaho reports i got the following error...please help me... thanks before hand...

---

Comment: Have you added the pentaho jar to your classpath?

Comment: thanks for reply...yeah, i added the pentaho jars..but still getting the same error...please help me ..

Comment: Tell us **how** you added them.

Comment: i'm using eclipse ide...i made it by rightclick on the project and configuring the build path... is there anything  wrong in that??

Comment: Does the jar appear in `WEB-INF/lib`? If not, that's where you should put it.

Comment: No, it appears in the library folder in the project

Comment: Then take the jar and manually place it in `WEB-INF/lib`. If such a folder doesn't exist, create it first.

Comment: I placed it in the WEB-INF/lib folder... but i still get the same error...please help me ..its very urgent..

Comment: It seems to me like you have the wrong jar. Open it (the jar) with a zip file manager and check if it contains a `.class` file for `org/pentaho/reporting/engine/classic/core/ClassicEngineBoot`

Comment: yeah, that .class file is there...can you tell the procedure r show me link for displaying the pentaho reports in servlets..please don't irritate for my simple questions..

Comment: The exception you have occurs because your classpath is not set up correctly. Read up on the classpath and you will find your problem. This has nothing to do with pentaho reports.

Comment: please dont get irritation for my  simple doubts..iam new to pentaho

Comment: did you have any link which contains the procedure for displaying the pentaho reports..

Comment: No and this question has nothing to do with pentaho reports.

Comment: ok..thanks for ur support

Comment: Good luck. Seriously, just make sure your classpath is set correctly.